# How can I search for a regular expression pattern but replace only a part of it using TCL?

Tags: regex, tcl

I have the following text:

```
T o m ' s " b o o k "
```

which needs to be converted to:

```
T o m' s" b o o k"
```

i.e, whenever there occurs a space between an alphabet and a special character, the space needs to be removed retaining the other part of the structure intact.

My attempt:

```
set word "T o m ' s \" b o o k \"";
set regex "\\w\ \[\"_@:\;,.'\]"
puts $regex;

 if {[regexp $regex $word]} {
            regsub " " $word "" word;
        }
puts $word
```

However that gives me the output:

```
To m ' s " b o o k "
```

How can I change the code to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with `regsub` as shown below.

```
set input {T o m ' s " b o o k "}
puts $input
puts [regsub -all {\s(\W)} $input {\1}]
```

**Output :**

```
T o m ' s " b o o k "
T o m' s" b o o k"
```

I have used `\s` to match the space and `\W` to match special characters. (i.e. non-word characters such as anything other than a letter, number or underscore)

Syntax of `regsub` as follows

> regsub ?switches? exp string subSpec ?varName?

Have a look at Tcl's [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regsub.htm) command.  The reason for using grouping in the regular expression like `\s(\W)` is to re-use the matched special character as a back reference by using `\1`. 
i.e. The space and special character matched by the pattern has to be replaced by the special character which is already matched by us in terms of the atom `\W`.

Take a look at [here](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml) to know about back referencing in `Tcl`.

Comment: I would be more specific though: look for a word char, a space and a non-word, non-space char: `regsub -all {(\w)\s([^\w\s])} $input {\1\2}` -- if the OP specifically wants to remove the space between a word char and a puncuation char: `{(\w)\s([[:punct:]])}`